# Searching an array for the number of occurrences that a string appears

Tags: java, arrays, string

In my java class, we are using junit test to test our methods. This section introduced using an interface.

this specific method I am having problems on is supposed to search an array at each index, looking for a matching string as the input.

In the junit test I have

```
    void test() 
    {
        MyClassList labTest = new MyClassList("CIS 120", "Fall", "Professor Awesome");

        MyStudent george = new MyStudent("George","Lucas", "555-555-5555","george.lucas@starwars.com");
        MyStudent gene = new MyStudent("Gene", "Roddenberry","666-666-6666", "gene.roddenberry@startrek.com");
        MyStudent jordan = new MyStudent("Jordan" ,"Robberts", "755-555-5555", "jordan.robberts@wheeloftime.com");

        labTest.insert(george);
        labTest.insert(gene);
        labTest.insert(jordan);

        System.out.println(labTest.toString());
        System.out.println(labTest.contains(george));
        System.out.println(labTest.search("George"));
```

This is the code U have for the method search:

Note

```
 protected MyStudent [] log;
 protected int lastIndex = -1;
```

are global variables

```
package Lab2;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import Lab2.ClassListInterFace;

public class MyClassList implements ClassListInterFace {
    protected String course;
    protected String semester;
    protected String teacherLastName;
    protected MyStudent[] log;
    protected int lastIndex = -1;

    public MyClassList(String currCourse,  String currSemester, String lastName, int maxSize) {
        log = new MyStudent[maxSize];
        this.course = currCourse;
        this.semester = currSemester;
        this.teacherLastName = lastName;
    }

    public MyClassList( String currCourse,  String currSemester, String lastName)

    {
        log = new MyStudent[100];
        this.course = currCourse;
        this.semester = currSemester;
        this.teacherLastName = lastName;
    }

    public void insert(MyStudent element) {
        lastIndex++;
        log[lastIndex] = element;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        if (lastIndex == (log.length - 1))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int size() {

        return (lastIndex + 1);
    }


    public void clear() 
    {
          for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++)
              log[i] = null;
            lastIndex = -1;

    }

    public String getName() {
         return teacherLastName;
    }


public boolean contains(MyStudent element) {

    boolean found = false;
    for( int location = 0;location <= lastIndex; location++)
    {
      if (element.equals(log[location]))  // if they match
        found = true;
}
    return found;
}

public String toString()
{
    String message = "Course " + course + "\n Semester " + semester + "\n Proffessor " + teacherLastName + "\n"; 
            for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                message += log[i].toString();
            }
    return message;
}

public int search(String x) 

{
    int answer = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < log.length; i++) 
     {
            if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(log[i]))
                answer++;
     }

    return answer;

}
```

I got this based off some code that the teacher gave us for reference, and I tweaked it a little.

Comment: Are you searching for the index where the string appears or the number of occurrences?

Comment: @AJ9P can you also post expected input and output.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that can be done much more elegantly with a `for` loop. In my experience, using a more concise control structure designed for things like this can lead to far fewer chances of errors. While I'm not sure what exact issue you are looking for help with, I do notice that if you do find a match, you skip the next element **without** checking to see if it is *also* a match.

```
    int location = 0;
    while (location <= lastIndex) 
    {
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(log[location])) 
        { // if they match
            answer ++;
            location ++;  //<-- Here's where you increment twice upon finding a match!
        }
        location++;  //To fix with the smallest number of changes, just put this in an else clause
    }
```

This entire block can be reduced to approximately half the lines and half the variables by changing it up to be a `for` loop. See below:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < log.length; i++) {
        if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(log[i].firstName))
            answer++;
    }
```

This is much easier to read, and far less prone to errors. Trying to keep track of an excessive number of variables or dividing out common operations (such as incrementing where you are) is just asking for issues. This four-liner is functionally equivalent to your above code block (aside from the fact it doesn't skip the following entry when it finds a match), yet has far fewer opportunities for a programmer to make a mistake. Always, when you can get away with it, use the control flow structure designed for the task.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I have an additional question, when i tried your code, eclipse says that .equalsIgnoreCase is not applicatable for the object MyStudent.
Do i need a toString line? thanks

Comment: If you are looking for a specific field in MyStudent, then you should reference that field. We can't see what MyStudent is, so we can only make assumptions based on what you wrote. .toString() may work, but we won't know unless you try it or give more insight as to what MyStudent actually is.

Comment: To clarify, I am looking to see if each index in the array has a certain string value in it. ei "George" and then return how many times "George" was in the array.

Comment: ```
MyClassList labTest = new MyClassList("CIS 120", "Fall", "Professor Awesome");
 
  MyStudent george = new MyStudent("George","Lucas", "555-555-5555","george.lucas@starwars.com");
  MyStudent gene = new MyStudent("Gene", "Roddenberry","666-666-6666", "gene.roddenberry@startrek.com");
  MyStudent jordan = new MyStudent("Jordan" ,"Robberts", "755-555-5555", "jordan.robberts@wheeloftime.com");
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the MyStudent class's fields or constructor?

Comment: i added the classlist file, minus the getters and setters, and the junit test file to that point

Comment: Based on the naming conventions I can see, I assume that the field you're looking for is called `firstName`, and you would reference it accordingly by using `log[i].firstName`, which I edited into my answer (note, if it's not public then you need to use the getter which is hopefully in there).

Comment: if i may ask you one final question. When i input your code, the code is happy, but when i run it, it gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException pointed at the for loop. I am searching how to fix this error, but i am comming up blank. thanks

Comment: When it initializes its internal `log` array it initializes it to a certain size, filling the rest with `null`. This wouldn't cause issues when comparing whole objects, but since you're referencing something within an object, a null will through an exception. So you'll need to check to see if `log[i] == null` before you check if the name matches.